# ATI driver on Linux.. which one to use?

Tags: linux, drivers, vga, amd-radeon

How should I say.. I know my way in Linux. I've been using Linux/BSD for a very long time. The problem is the ATI driver. I want to install OpenSUSE on my laptop (too much free time? :)).

But. WHICH Ati driver should I use?
First there was an open-source (xf86-ati ?) and the prop ATI one. Okay. Then RadeonHD showed up. First, it was the messiah for all the ATI users. Recently I read that even OpenSUSE, a main character in this driver abandoned it.

The proprietary driver suc.. *cough* is bad. That's alright. But which open-source driver should I use?

The hardware is an ATI mRadeon HD3650. (In my case. But basically all the 3000+ Radeons. As far as I remember the main ATI driver won't support it. On Windows, it does. But even the Windows driver is a piece of.. crap.)
(Not sure if I should convert this to community wiki or not. If yes, please comment.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`http://xorg.freedesktop.org/wiki/radeon` seems to have the lowdown:

> Radeon has some features not available in radeonhd and vice versa, but generally they are starting to be quite close while *radeon* supports all the cards and *radeonhd* only r5xx-r7xx.

I believe that the *radeon* driver now has the same or better support as *radeonhd*. The ["ATI Hardware" section of the "openSUSE Graphic Card Practical Theory Guide for Users"](http://forums.opensuse.org/english/information-new-users/advanced-how-faq-read-only/438705-opensuse-graphic-card-practical-theory-guide-users.html#post2164512) seems to concur:

> As of openSUSE-11.3 Milestone6 Novell/SuSE-GmbH have announced this driver superseded by the radeon driver, so it is possible the radeon driver may function better on RadeonHD hardware than the radeonhd.

I am not an OpenSUSE user, but the *radeon* driver seems to be contained in the *xorg-x11-driver-video* package, while *radeonhd* is provided by *xorg-x11-driver-video-radeonhd*.

Comment: Oh okay. Today I just read the Phoronix article about the issue and seems like radeon is the future, radeonhd is dead. Hope they will write a usable driver since the prop is the worst both on Linux and Windows. (Not to mention there is no driver for BSD.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm  using the radeon driver of X.org on my system (Fedora 12, ATI HD 4000 Series). It works well for me.

Answer (score 0):

`radeonhd` is dead, as other posters have mentioned.

The free `radeon` driver is actually a bundle of drivers, and it should autodetect which driver is needed for your card.